# java opencv error insufficient memory and assertion failed

Tags: java, opencv, memory

I am working in java on a program that uses the opencv library to take a folder of images and crop just the faces. It uses face recognition from opencv. I got it to work, but when I try it with a larger folder of images it stops with these errors:

> OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 411068928 bytes) in cv::OutOfMemoryError, file C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 52 OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (u != 0) in cv::Mat::create, file C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 411 Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:411: error: (-215) u != 0 in function cv::Mat::create ] at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale_1(Native Method) at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(CascadeClassifier.java:103) at FaceDetector.main(FaceDetector.java:42)

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthSeparatorUI;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

public class FaceDetector {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");

    CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("C:/Users/Family/workspace/detect face/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");

    File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\Family\\Downloads\\Photos (4)");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int j = 0; j < listOfFiles.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(listOfFiles[j]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length-1; i++){
        String picname = listOfFiles[i].toString();

        System.out.println("reading: " + listOfFiles[i]);

        Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(picname);

        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

        System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));


        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
            Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar (0, 255, 0));
        }

        Rect recta = new Rect();

        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
            recta.x = rect.x;
            recta.y = rect.y;
            recta.width = rect.width;
            recta.height = rect.height;
        }


        if (faceDetections.toArray().length == 1) {
            BufferedImage picture = ImageIO.read(new File(picname));
            BufferedImage croppedImage = picture.getSubimage(recta.x, recta.y, recta.width, recta.height);

//              File finalCropped = new     File(listOfFiles[i].toString()+"cropped.jpg");
            File finalCropped = new File("C:/Users/Family/Downloads/CroppedImages/" + "cropped" + (i + 140) + ".jpg");

            ImageIO.write(croppedImage, "jpg", finalCropped);

            System.out.println("Cropping " + i + "/" + listOfFiles.length);

        }

        faceDetections.release();
    }
    System.out.println("Process complete.");

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should release `image` object too. I would like to suggest to use a try catch finally for proper release.

```
image.release();
```

Comment: I did this and the program got further than last time, but it stopped at the same error. I'm just going to try with a shorter amount of images.

Comment: well that did nothing

Comment: You might want to call System.gc() if the loop count is divisible by some number like 5 or 10. You also need to release the Mat objects loaded by  Imgcodecs.imread too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to increase the Heap Space ? Have a look [here](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space).

The java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error will be triggered when the application attempts to add more data into the heap space area, but there is not enough room for it.